# MPD gives no audio from HDMI on PI-zero

Tags: alsa, hdmi

I run MPD on a PI-zero. When configured the audio systen to analog (3.5mm jack) it runs ok.
But when changed to HDMI and a HDMI splitter no sound comes out.
When using “aplay” or “speaker-test” all is ok.

I wonder if the problem comes from the audio-output section in the mpd.conf file.
There is a line like: device “hw: 0,0”
What does this 0,0 mean? Is an explanation written somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

l`, and`aplay -L` to see the cards and devices on your Pi.

Documentation for ALSA is old and all over the place.  I found this site helpful:  https://alsa.opensrc.org​